# How to parse value of (lat,long) php

Tags: php, parsing, google-maps, coordinates

I need to parse the values of `(47.624718,-122.356133)` or example or (lat,long) pair.

That url is generated by the following JS:

```
var html = \"<b>\" + name + \"</b> <br/>\" + address + \"<br><br>\" + \"<a id='myLink' href='result.php?\"+point+\"'>Professors here</a>\";
```

the `point` var is generated by this js var:

```
var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute(\"lat\")),parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute(\"lng\")));
```

Obviously these values vary in size/length based on point on google maps, so how do I parse this using php to get anything before the `,` and everything after the `,` besides the `()` into two variables?

Thanks

Comment: Quick note: \" Is not needed here...

Comment: What does your input string look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php > preg_match("/(-?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?),(-?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?)/","(42.3,-59.0)",$matches); print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => 42.3,-59.0
    [1] => 42.3
    [2] => .3
    [3] => -59.0
    [4] => .0
)
php >
```

The indexes are ordered like that because of the way the parenthesis are nested. Just use index 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

you can write it more concisely then that, but it is easy to follow this way

```
$latlon = "(42.3,-59.0)"; 
list($lat, $lon) = string_to_lat_lon($latlon);

function string_to_lat_lon($string) {
    $string = str_replace('(', '', $string); // remove leading bracket
    $string = str_replace(')', '', $string); // remove trailing bracket
    return explode(',', $string);
}
```

Comment: you can only match one pair though. with regexes you can just change to preg_match_all